# How to print the Field Value if it has an empty string in the list in Java

Tags: java, spring, maven, jsp

```
[name="zakir", salary="44003", designation=""]
[name="Sheela", salary="24303", designation="Developer"]
[name="Meghana", salary="100000", designation="Tester"]
```

In the above eaxmple i want to print the name which does not have any thing in designation i.e. the empty string object in a jsp pages under a dropdown.

Note: i am working under **Spring MVC model**, just help me out the logic where i can just extract the zakir in a seperate list.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6borK.png)

Comment: What does the code look like? If you are extending `JpaRepository`, you can just add the method signature such as `List<Employee> findAllByDesignationIsNull();`.

Comment: you can filter out employees where designation is empty, for example:
`employees.stream().filter(e -> !e.getDesignation().isEmpty()).collect(Collectors.toList())`

Comment: yes that might can work but i am having a dao.java file where i have written all my save, delete, and update query. @CalvinP.

Comment: employees.stream().filter(e -> !e.getDesignation().isEmpty()).collect(Collectors.toList()) this is bringing all the elements from the list @TrandafirEmanuel, PLz suggest any other approach

Comment: @hussain In that case you can build the same query in whatever manner you are already using. Hibernate example, `String query = "select e from Employee e where e.designation is null";`

Comment: thank you @CalvinP. but there is cache again "null" will not affect the empty strings, whenever the user is entering the data from the view side any empty field will be taken as an empty string i.e. " " , not NULL

Comment: @hussain As long as you're sure that all 'empty' strings contain no whitespace, you could instead write is such as `String query = "select e from Employee e where e.designation = ''"`. If you want to catch both, `String query = "select e from Employee e where e.designation = '' or e.designation is null"`

Comment: @CalvinP. this is not helping out can you suggest anything using java, so that i can use it inside the controller

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Emp> unlist = dao.getEmployees();
List<Emp> emptyFields = new ArrayList<>();
for (Emp person : unlist) {
    if (person.getDesignation().equals("") || person.getDesignation().equals(""))
        {
           emptyFields.add(person);
        }
    }
        
        // viewing the lists in the jsp
        m.addAttribute("unlist_dropdown", emptyFields);
```